# Symfony, TinyMCE and Bootstrap Lightbox

Tags: tinymce, lightbox

Within a Symfony developed blog app, I have defined -by [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) and its plugin [Justboil.me](https://github.com/vikdiesel/justboil.me)-  a form with a RTE textarea to create some text + images, say at url http://localhost/myApp/Blog/1/Post/6/**edit**.

Hence, text+images is rendered at url http://localhost/myApp/Blog/1/Post/6. So far so good.

Now I would like to have a lightbox effect too, by [Bootstrap Lightbox](http://jbutz.github.io/bootstrap-lightbox/).

So question is, how do I get TinyMCE to create the html that Bootstrap Lightbox needs? I am not sure how to do.

If I try to insert the following code by hand

```
<div class="example">
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span2"><a class="thumbnail" href="#demoLightbox" data-toggle="lightbox"> <img src="/bundles/myBundle/imgta/myImage.jpg" alt="Click to view the lightbox" /> </a></li>
</ul>
<div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1">
<div class="lightbox-content"><img src="/bundles/myBundle/imgta/myImage.jpg" />
<div class="lightbox-caption">
<p>Your caption here</p>
</div> </div></div></div>
```

I get a messy popup box, <del>but it contains the entire front end page itself http://localhost/myApp/Blog/1/Post/6, instead that just the image with its caption. Somehow, this is because the link above is rendered as http://localhost/myApp/Blog/1/Post/6#demoLightbox/</del> (this was beacuse I had two conflicting pieces of JS)

I am lost!
thanks, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it turned out to be easy to fix things. The following two steps are good enough:

A. My Symfony 3.4 developed blog includes a `show.html.twig` template to render the single view of a post of the blog. (If you are familiar with Symfony, you know what I am saying).

Add the following JS + css + html lines therein:

```
  {% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{{ asset('bundles/myblog/css/bootstrap-lightbox/bootstrap-lightbox.css') }}"  media="all" />
  {% endblock %}

  {% block javascripts %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/myblog/js/bootstrap-lightbox/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js') }}"></script> 


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.pop').on('click', function() {
        $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $('.lightbox-caption').html( $(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });     
   });
   </script>
   {% endblock %}

  ....

  <div id="imagemodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body"><button class="close" type="button" data-     dismiss="modal">&times;<span class="sr-only">Close</span></button> 
  <img class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" />
  <div class="lightbox-caption">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

B. Hack `Justboil.me` just a little. File `dialog.v4.js`, line 63, wrap output with `<a class="pop" href="#"> | </a>`:

```
 tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.insertContent('<a class="pop" href="#"> <img src="' + result.filename +'"></a>');
```

tha's all!